# Boundedness of characteristic function (using Fourier transform)

Tags: probability, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Its Fourier transform is denoted $\mu'$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by
$$
\mu'(u)= \int e^{i\langle u,x\rangle} \mu(dx)
$$
Now it says that it follows that
$$
|\mu'|\leq \int |e^{i\langle u,x\rangle}| \mu(dx) = \int 1 \mu(dx) = 1
$$
now I understand the first steps, but can't understand why $\int 1 \mu(dx) = 1$ in the end. Writing it as characteristic functions I get it, because there $E(1)=1$ using the expected value. How is $\int 1 \mu(dx) = 1$ here? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu$ is a probability measure and thus

$$\int 1 \mu(dx) = \mu(\mathbb{R}^n) = 1$$

Recall that $1$ is the indicator function on the set $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the integral of an indicator function $I_A$ is (by definition of the Lebesgue-integral) equal to the measure of $A$, i.e. $\mu(A)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, but why do we get the indicator function? I tought that we get the penultimate equation because of $|e^{i\langle u,x\rangle}|=1$?

Comment: $I_{\mathbb{R}^n}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is the function that is $1$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $0$ elsewhere, thus in this case $I_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is equal to the constant $1$ function. Does that solve your problem? In your proof it is indeed also used that $|e^{i \langle u, x \rangle}| = 1$.

Comment: Aaaah, absolutely. Thank you very much! I can verify your answer in 2 min :)

Comment: Thanks! Glad to help!